# problemas com consulta em hql

Tags: java

Estou fazendo um projeto de cadastro.
O objetivo é cadastrar e consultar clientes e funcionários, no entanto, já é possível salvar os dados, o problema é consultar.
para consulta fiz formulários JPanel(estou usando netbeans), onde para consultar deve-se preencher o campo nome e Email para ambos formulários e então basta clicar no botão consultar.

o código que inseri no botão consultar é o seguinte:

```
ClienteControle cc = new ClienteControle();
        try {
            List<Cliente> ListaDeClientes = cc.buscar(txbNome.getText(),
                    txbEmail.getText());
            DefaultTableModel model =
                    (DefaultTableModel) tbResultados.getModel();
            for (int i = model.getRowCount() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                model.removeRow(i);
            }
            if (ListaDeClientes != null) {
                for (int i = 0; i < ListaDeClientes.size(); i++) {
                    Cliente cliente = ListaDeClientes.get(i);
                    String[] c = new String[]{
                        cliente.getNome(),
                        cliente.getEmail()};
                    model.insertRow(i, c);
                }
            }
            tbResultados.setModel(model);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,
                    "Não foi possível realizar a consulta de clientes!\n\n"
                    + e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
```

No código acima instanciei a classe ClienteControle que tem o seguinte método:

```
public List<Cliente> buscar(String nome, String email)
            throws Exception {
        return null;
    }
```

Depois criei o seguinte método dentro da classe ClienteDAO para que pudesse consultar perante a conexão com o banco de dados:

```
public List<Cliente> getListaDeClientes(String nome, String email)
            throws Exception {
       EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
       try {
           String hql ="";
           if(nome != null && !nome.equals("")) {
               hql += " WHERE nome like upper (:nome)";
           }
           if (email != null && !email.equals("")) {
               if (!hql.equals("")) {
                   hql += " AND email like lower(:email)";
               } else {
                   hql += " WHERE email like lower(:email)";
               }
           }
           hql = "FROM Cliente" + hql;
           Query q = em.createQuery(hql);
           if(nome != null && !nome.equals("")) {
               q.setParameter("nome", "%" +
                       nome.toLowerCase() + "&");
           }
           if (email != null & !email.equals("")) {
               q.setParameter("email", "%" +
                       email.toLowerCase() + "%");
           }
           return q.getResultList();
       } finally {
           em.close();
       }
    }
```

E depois alterei o método buscar do ClienteControle para:

```
public List<Cliente> buscar(String nome, String email)
            throws Exception {
        return new ClienteDAO().getListaDeClientes(nome, email);
    }
```

O botão deveria executar normalmente mas aparece essas mensagens de erro:

> Exception Description: An exception was thrown while searching for
>   pesistence archives with ClassLoader:
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@5c647e05
>
> Internal Exception: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception
>   [EclipseLink-28018](Eclipse Persistense Services -
>   2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
>
> Exception Exception Description: Predeployment of
>   PersistenceUnit[CadastroPU]
>   failed.org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
>
> Internal Exception: Exception [EclipseLink-7299](Eclipse Persistence
>   Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd)
>
> Exception Description: Conflicting annotations with the same name
>   [SEQ_STORE] were found. the first one
>   [@javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator({allocationSize=20,
>   name=SEQ_STORE, sequenceName= funcionario_seq})] was found within
>   [class cadastro.Pessoa.Funcionario] and the second
>   [@javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator({allocationSize=20,
>   name=SEQ_STORE, sequenceName=cliente_seq})] was found within [class
>   cadastro.Pessoa.Cliente]. Named annotations must be unique across the
>   persistence unit.

Por que aparece isso? tem como solucionar?

Comment: De acordo com esse erro: `Exception Description: Conflicting annotations with the same name [SEQ_STORE] were found. the first one [@javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator({allocationSize=20, name=SEQ_STORE, sequenceName= funcionario_seq})] was found within [class cadastro.Pessoa.Funcionario] and the second [@javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator({allocationSize=20, name=SEQ_STORE, sequenceName=cliente_seq})] was found within [class cadastro.Pessoa.Cliente]. Named annotations..` conflitos de annotations. posta sua classe Cliente e Funcionario ou tente mudar o atributo `name` de `@SequenceGenerator`.

Answer (score 2):

Seu erro está bem claro nessa linha:

> Exception Description: **Conflicting annotations with the same name [SEQ_STORE] were found**. the first one [@javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator({allocationSize=20, name=SEQ_STORE, sequenceName= funcionario_seq})] was found within [class cadastro.Pessoa.Funcionario] and the second [@javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator({allocationSize=20, name=SEQ_STORE, sequenceName=cliente_seq})] was found within [class cadastro.Pessoa.Cliente]. Named annotations must be unique across the persistence unit.

Veja que você chamou de SEQ_STORE duas sequences diferentes: funcionario_seq e cliente_seq. Para ajustar é necessário apenas renomear uma delas, por exemplo:

```
... ({allocationSize=20, name=SEQ_STORE_FUNCIONARIO, sequenceName= funcionario_seq})
```

Comment: eu já havia feito o procedimento, porém apareceu outra exceção ao criar uma consulta no entityManager, a descrição é a seguinte: An exception occurred while creating a query in entityManager:
Exception Description: Syntax error parsing [FROM Cliente WHERE nome like upper (:nome) AND email like lower(:email)].
[13,13] An identification variable must be provided for a range variable declaration. Caso puder ajudar, fico agradecido

Comment: para um melhor entendimento, tirei esse print.   https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FrDqMr_z2ZO51zN0tNt3ZkU1LPIt7XJh/view

Comment: @Luan, nesse caso é outro erro, então você precisa criar outra pergunta, ok? Quando criar me avisa que olho lá pra te ajudar.

Answer (score 0):

Bom dia Luan, como você alterou o nome da sequence e apresentou outra a exceção você precisa declarar um identificador para sua entidade na query, tente isso:

```
hql += " WHERE c.nome like upper (:nome)";


if (!hql.equals("")) {
                   hql += " AND c.email like lower(:email)";
               } else {
                   hql += " WHERE c.email like lower(:email)";
               }

hql = "FROM Cliente c" + hql;
```

Comment: Isto não fornece uma resposta à pergunta. Para criticar ou solicitar esclarecimento de um autor, deixe um comentário abaixo da publicação dele. - [Da Revisão](/review/low-quality-posts/157044)

Comment: Me expressei mal, no caso a resposta era para o [comentário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/282699/problemas-com-consulta-em-hql/282833?noredirect=1#comment577228_282703) que ele fez relatando outra exceção.